To wait a file to be created, with a timeout, and a error message, in Applescript
in my AppleScript app, I have to wait for a file to be created by an another app, with a timeout (to not waiting for ever), and with an error message if the timeout is over.
I've tried that, but without success:

testing if the file exists is working well
the timeout doesn't work : it repeat forever
the last try is the only way I found to show the message and quit. Better solution ?

set SetPNG to (DossierDeBase & "pdf-lightroom:set copie.png")

with timeout of 5 seconds
    repeat
        try
            SetPNG as alias -- test if the file exist
            exit repeat
        on error
            
        end try
    end repeat
end timeout

try
    SetPNG as alias
on error
    display alert "The file has not been generated."
    quit
end try


:)

The with timeout statement only works for commands sent to another application, so you will need to create your own.

Perhaps I'm too novice, but how? :)

This should work as a script or as an app.
-- set SetPNG to (path to desktop as text) & "crap" -- used for testing
set SetPNG to (DossierDeBase & "pdf-lightroom:set copie.png")

set ft to false -- false or true that file exists
set notaTimer to 0
set loopTime to 3 -- checks every 3 seconds

repeat until notaTimer is equal to 30
    try
        tell application "Finder" to set ft to exists file SetPNG -- true or false
        if ft then -- if true
            exit repeat
        end if
        set notaTimer to notaTimer + loopTime
        delay loopTime
    end try
end repeat


if ft then
    alias SetPNG
    display notification "File `" & SetPNG & "` exists"
else
    display alert "Nothing to see here" giving up after 4
end if


The main issue with using delays in repeat loops is that the UI gets blocked.  Depending on what else the application is doing, a NSTimer can be used - an idle handler (which also uses a timer) would be similar.

@red_menace In what way does the UI get blocked? Except for the alert's intrusion, I am able to work normally with other applications, including the Finder. Indeed, part of my testing involves using the Finder to create a matching file in the target location. Or are you referring to the extraneous delay (eg the remainder of loopTime) after the file match is done?

I am referring to the script application's UI.  Script applications don't have the hooks that a script editor does - for example, run your script as an application and try to quit it while it is in the repeat loop.

I see what you mean. Obviously, it has a finite timeout period but to quit it before that point, I had to force-quit it. Thanks for clarifying.
